# Is there one simple word which means the inverse of the word "apply"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I am looking for a simple word which would mean the opposite of the word "apply". The first thing that comes to my mind is "unapply". But I am not sure if it is elegant and maybe there is something better?

I have curves on my chart and I want to update those curves with another curve (not create a new curve on the chart but I want the old curve to be updated with new values from the other curve). So in that case I would say: “Apply other curve in (or on) old curve”. And now I need to say to do opposite, so probably “Subtract other curve from old curve” would be ok. But I was wondering if there is any special word corresponding exactly to “apply”.

Comment: Welcome! The word '[apply](https://www.lexico.com/definition/apply)' can have different meanings: please show an example sentence of how it is to be used, and another showing how its inverse will be used.

Comment: Hello, pajczur. It is often not a simple process to identify 'the opposite' of a  word. For instance, think of 'eat'. Is 'the opposite' 'refuse to eat', 'fast', 'regurgitate' ...? // Here, a sentence showing the sense of 'apply' you wish to have 'the opposite' of  is essential. 'She applied for the vacant position.' / 'He applied for the grant.' /  'He applied another coat of varnish'.  / 'He applied the brakes.' /  'In such cases, maritime law applies.' / ' You need to apply yourself to your studies. / ....

Comment: I mean I have curves on my chart and I want to update those curves with other curve (not create new curve on chart but want the old curve to be updated with new values from other curve). So in that case I would say: “Apply other curve in (or on) old curve”. And now I need to say to do opposite, so probably “Subtract other curve from old curve” would be ok. But i was wondering if there is any special word corresponding exactly to “apply”.

Comment: Hmm... Somebody edited my question and now it looks really nice. Great thanks for that. In the future I will try to make my questions more like that.

Comment: Perhaps "undo the previous curve adjustment".

Comment: What @WeatherVane said. It's misleading to characterise this question as a request for an "opposite" to the word ***apply***, since the requested term would *only* be an antonym for the highly restricted sense of ***apply X = carry out some action identified / defined by X***. For which the opposite is expressed by terms such as ***undo, regress, revert,...***

Comment: You could even coin "unapply", which would be easily understood and fine for software (Lexico has "unapplied" but not the verb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the hopes of answering the question graphically:

[image: Curves]